# Detect double-click mouse event in a MKMapView (not iOS touch event)

Tags: macos, mkmapview

I am writing a custom app using a MKMapView, and I need add a place mark in the map by clicking in the map view, but the mouseDown method is never called. I can not find any doc in the apple developer help.

Place a MKAnnotation is not problem.

Any one can help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to disable mouse interaction with the MKMapView, by setting the scrollEnabled and zoomEnabled properties to No.

Once those are set the mouseDown and other mouse events fire as expected.